# Trinidad Nested panelTabbed not working

Tags: jsf, tabs, myfaces, oc4j, trinidad

I'm having some trouble using Trinidad's .

I have 1 main panelTab and a secondary one inside one of the main's panel showDetailItem.

The problem is :

When i switch tabs on the main one "tabbedPanel" everything works as expected, but when I click on the second set of tabs "tabbedPanel2" a request is sent to the server but the first tab always remains selected.

Here is the code :

```
<tr:form>
    <t:saveState value="#{monBean}" id="monBean" />

<tr:panelTabbed id="tabbedPanel"
   attributeChangeListener="#{monBean.changeEvent}"
   >
      <tr:showDetailItem text="Tab 1"
          disclosureListener="#{monBean.ongletSelectionne}"
          id="tab1"
            >
      </tr:showDetailItem>

      <tr:showDetailItem text="Tab 2" id="tab2"
          disclosureListener="#{monBean.ongletSelectionne}"
       >

          <tr:panelTabbed id="tabbedPanel2">

              <tr:showDetailItem id="tab21"
                     disclosureListener="#{monBean.ongletSelectionne}"
                     text="Tab 2.1"
               >

             </tr:showDetailItem>

             <tr:showDetailItem id="tab22"
                      disclosureListener="#{monBean.ongletSelectionne}"
                      text="Tab 2.2"
              >

                  <tr:outputText value="#{monBean.msg}" id="wrapper" />
             </tr:showDetailItem>

           </tr:panelTabbed>

       </tr:showDetailItem>


</tr:panelTabbed>
```

The weird thing though is that if I switch to Client State Saving instead of server state saving, everythin works properly.

Any ideas?

Environnement :

- Trinidad 1.2.14
- MyFaces 1.2.11
- Tomahawk 1.1.11
- Oracle OC4j 10.1.3.4